# Why is it bad to share an API Key in code repos/forums/etc?

Tags: javascript, api, security, key, api-key

I have had people explain to me that its bad to post your API key, but what if I created an api key that was for free? Does it matter that I am still sharing my api key in order to get help with a project issue?

If it is a threat to share a free API key, does that mean some sort of crazy scenario happens where a person latches onto my api key and somehow traces it back and gets inside of my computer??

Comment: what if your api key has usage limits. (say for a email service provider 1000 emails/month) and someone else is using yours

Comment: Someone will get your api key banned by sending thousand of requests in a minute